# Pytest: Patch a global variable

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

How do you patch a variable with mock or pytest-mock.  Assume the variable is defined in another python script and is used by many other scripts.  I would like to mock it within `pytest_cmdline_main` so that all the scripts using that variable will be mocked accordingly.

A quick example will be

## in env.py

```
VAR = "something"
```

## in conftest.py

```
import os
import sys
from unittest.mock import patch


TEST_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


class MockThings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        mock_var = patch('env.VAR').start()
        mock_var.return_value = "updated"


def pytest_cmdline_main(config):
    sys.path.append(TEST_DIR)
    MockThings()
```

## in test_something.py

```
from env import VAR


def test_sample():
    print(VAR)
    # do something else here
    assert False
    
def test_sample2():
    print(VAR)
    # do something else here
    assert False
```

When you run `pytest -v`

The test will fail as expected, but under the stdout it will state something like: `<MagicMock name='VAR' id='140102687826416'>`

Because it is treating the mock as a function, if I replace the `print(VAR)` with `print(VAR())` then the print out will be correct (`updated`).

How do I mock this variable, and not treat it as a function?  I know you can just set `VAR="updated"` in the test function itself, but I just want it mocked and I guess this is not a great representation of my actual use case, but I just wanted to have a quick simple test code you can run and understand easily.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `env.py` like this:

```py
VAR = "something"

def func():
    return VAR
```

Then, in `test_something.py`, you could mock `VAR` like this:

```py
import pytest

from env.py import func


@pytest.fixture
def var(mocker):
    return mocker.patch("env.VAR", new="updated", autospec=False)


def test_func(var):
    print(func())
    assert func() == "updated"
```

In which case, running `pytest . -v -s` will print out:

> test_something.py::test_func **updated**
> **PASSED**

Comment: `fixture 'mocker' not found`

Comment: You need first to pip install `pytest-mock` plugin. See https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for additional guidance.

Comment: I have a similar case, the only difference is env.py doesn't define VAR='something'. I tried pytest.fixture as you mentioned here, but failed. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to mock, then? Cheers.